# Google Script Triggered by Form Submit Sometimes Doesn't Work

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms, eventtrigger

I have a script that reads answers from a Google form when it is sent. The script is bound to a spreadsheet, that captures all answers. The script generates a PDF with some information and sends it to a user via GmailApp, and stores the PDF inside a Drive folder. But sometimes the script doesn't work.  The answers are always stored in the spreadsheet, but despite this, the script doesn't run.  I have checked the "Execution transcript", but it contains information about the last successful execution.

How can I guarantee that the script always runs?

Can anyone explain why this happens?

### Code

```
//ID del template
var docTemplate = "Template ID Here";
//Nombre de la copia
var docName = "biovenCIP";

//FUnción principal para generación y envío de constancia
function onFormSubmit(e){
  //Leyendo datos del formulario
  var d = new Date();
  var registration_date = e.values[0];
  var first_name = e.values[1];
  var second_name = e.values[2];
  var first_lastname = e.values[3];
  var second_lastname = e.values[4];
  var document_type = e.values[5];
  var document_number = e.values[6];
  var email_address = e.values[7];
  var occupation = e.values[8];
  var category = e.values[9];
  var payment_number = e.values[10];
  var payment_date = e.values[11];

  //Inicializando mensaje opcional
  var occupation_message = " ";

  //Generando el nombre completo
  if(second_name.localeCompare("") != 0){
    second_name = " " + second_name;
  }
  if(second_lastname.localeCompare("") != 0){
    second_lastname = " " + second_lastname;
  }
  var full_name = first_name + second_name + " " + first_lastname + second_lastname;
  full_name = full_name.replace(/\s+/g," ");

  //Generando compia del template  
  var copyID = DocsList.getFileById(docTemplate).makeCopy(docName + '_' + document_number).getId();
  var copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyID);
  var copyBody = copyDoc.getActiveSection();

  //Reemplazando texto en el template
  copyBody.replaceText('keyDate', registration_date);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyFullName', full_name);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyIDType', document_type);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyIDNumber', document_number);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyEmail', email_address);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyOccupation', occupation);
  switch(occupation){
      case "Estudiante de pregrado":
      occupation_message = "(presente carnet el primer día del evento)";
      var payment_worth = 100.00;
      break
      case "Estudiante de postgrado":
      occupation_message = "(presente carnet el primer día del evento)";
      var payment_worth = 150.00;
      break
      case "Profesional":
      var payment_worth = 200.00;
      break
  }
  copyBody.replaceText('keyOMessage', occupation_message);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyCategory', category);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyPaymentNum', payment_number);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyPaymentDate', payment_date);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyPayment', payment_worth)
  copyDoc.saveAndClose();

  //Convertir temporalmente a PDF
  var pdf = DocsList.getFileById(copyID).getAs("application/pdf");

  //Adjuntando PDF y enviado correo electrónico
  var reply_email = "info@bioven.org.ve";
  var bcc_email = "congresobioven@gmail.com";
  var subject = "Constancia de inscripción - BIOVEN 2015";
  var body = "Estimado " + full_name + ",<br/><br/> A través de este correo electrónico le hacemos entrega de su constancia de inscripción en el V Congreso Venezolano de Bioingeniería - BIOVEN 2015, la cual deberá presentar el primer día del congreso durante la verificación de registro.<br/><br/> Agradecidos,<br/><br/> <b>Comité Organizador del BIOVEN 2015</b>";
  GmailApp.sendEmail(email_address, subject, body, {name: 'Congreso BIOVEN 2015', bcc: bcc_email, htmlBody: body, replyTo: reply_email, attachments: pdf});

  //Guardando PDF en Drive
  var folder_id = "Folder ID Here";
  DriveApp.getFolderById(folder_id).createFile(pdf);

  //Borrando archivo DOC temporal
  DocsList.getFileById(copyID).setTrashed(true);
}
```

Comment: My solution would be to make a Webapp and publish it, garanteed 100% that every send would work.

Comment: @Kriggs So, this is a normal issue?

Comment: @Kriggs How can I do that?

Comment: in the script editor  > ressources>triggers you can set notification to "send immediately" (or something like that ;-), this will send you an error notification along with some info about what happened. Or you can wrap your code in a try/catch that would send you a msg when the "try" fails. The script probably runs but simply fails. Publishing as a webapp won't change anything.

Comment: @Sergeinsas I have already set notifications, the script works well but sometimes it simply doesn't, hence it doesn't generates "Execution transcription" neither notifications. :(

Comment: I have changed the script place, now it is bound into the form, maybe this helps to avoid the issue.

Comment: maybe you could add an unconditional mail send to check whether it runs or not

Answer (score 0):

Try defining your variable `payment_worth` higher up in the code:

```
function onFormSubmit(e){
  //Leyendo datos del formulario
  var d = new Date();
  //Other var definitions
  var payment_worth = 0;
```

Give it an initial value of zero.  Presently, if your **Case/Select** ever fails, the variable `payment_worth` would be undefined.

[image: Reference Error]

Just an idea.  Don't know if it's a good idea.  ;)

Case Select would look like this:

```
switch(occupation){
  case "Estudiante de pregrado":
  occupation_message = "(presente carnet el primer día del evento)";
  payment_worth = 100.00;
  break
  case "Estudiante de postgrado":
  occupation_message = "(presente carnet el primer día del evento)";
  payment_worth = 150.00;
  break
  case "Profesional":
  payment_worth = 200.00;
  break
}
```